# Which file to configure Http Post Authentication for nutch1.13

Tags: nutch

I am going to crawl a website using Nutch1.13, but the website needs http post authentication.I found that Nutch wiki has some content about it: [HttpPostAuthentication](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/HttpPostAuthentication).

It said:

> A configuration file with a list of domains for which authentication should be done along with the login URL and POST data.

I wonder which file i should put the configuration information in?
I didn't find any concrete example in the article.

I also find another link:[NUTCH-827](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-827). So do i need to make changes to the source code and rebuild to achieve Http Post Authentication or changes has already be made in nutch1.13?

Answer (score 1):

To specify which file Nutch will need to load with your configuration you should use the `http.auth.file` key in your `nutch-site.xml`, you can take a look at the example configuration provided in the `httpclient-auth.xml.template`. Especially starting at this line https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/httpclient-auth.xml.template#L61.

Keep in mind that you'll need to enable the `protocol-httpclient` plugin. And finally you will not need to modify Nutch as the status of the NUTCH-827 states this was resolved and merged since v1.10.

Comment: Hi, Luis. Thanks for your attention. I have already enable protocol-httpclient plugin in nutch-site.xml.And i also set configuration in http-clientauth.xml.But when i run nutch, it reports an error when fetching.It says "No form exists: lzform".  "lzform" is the id of the form which i want  to post. The error appears even when i test an url which i don't specify in http-clientauth.xml.